# Tinydns create a seperate A-Record for "www" and for my root domain

Tags: linux, debian, hosting, tinydns

I am having issues understanding how I should adapting the following configuration for tinydns so that the A-Records for "www" and for my root domain.

1. "www" pointing to 199.34.228.100.
2. root domain pointing to 199.34.228.100.

This would leave the current mails and only pointing the web to this new ip address.

"mail.test.com" is our separate mail server.

Current config:

```
# NS and SOA records
.test.co.uk::a.ns.bytemark.co.uk
.test.co.uk::b.ns.bytemark.co.uk
.test.co.uk::c.ns.bytemark.co.uk

# MX record - mail server
@test.co.uk::mail.test.com:10

# PTR records
+test.co.uk:80.68.48.137
+*.test.co.uk:80.68.48.137

# mail access
+mail.test.co.uk:80.68.48.137
+pop3.test.co.uk:80.68.48.137
+smtp.test.co.uk:80.68.48.137

#SPF records
'test.co.uk:v=spf1  mx  ~all:3600
```

Reference: http://cr.yp.to/djbdns/tinydns-data.html
Example: http://www.bytemark.co.uk/support/technical_documents/dnsc_example?tags=DNS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the A records for your hostnames properly, which is done by preceding the Hostname by a `=`:

```
# A Records
=test.co.uk:199.34.228.100:86400
=www.test.co.uk:199.34.228.100:86400
```

This should give you the expected result.

And don't forget to "compile" your `data` file afterwards.

Comment: Thank you, would this need to replace any of the existing config? Or add this below the name servers?

Comment: Add it somewhere in the file, for example at the end.